# WiX: How to change installation location based on radio button selection?

Tags: wix

I have a `RadioButtonGroup` of 3 `RadioButtons` having values `All`, `Easy` and `Gate`. The `RadioButtonGroup` is targeting a property named `FRAMEWORK`.

I want that

1.When I will click `All`, the Installation Folder will become `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arons Medical\`

2.When I will click `EASY`, the installation location will become `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arons Medical\Easy`

3.When I will click `GATE`, the installation location will become `C:\Program Files (x86)\GATE`

What will be the *WiX* code for this? I can guess I have to chane the `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` property, but how?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
    <Control Id="RadioButtonGroupID" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="30" Y="94" Width="305" Height="100" Property="TargetSystem">
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="TargetSystem">
        <RadioButton Value="live" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" Height="10" Text="Live" ToolTip="C:\Live" />
        <RadioButton Value="dev" X="0" Y="20" Width="300" Height="10" Text="Dev" ToolTip="C:\Test" />
        <RadioButton Value="user" X="0" Y="40" Width="300" Height="10" Text="User" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
    </Control>

    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
      <Publish Property="INSTALLDIR" Value="C:\Test">TargetSystem = "dev"</Publish>
      <Publish Property="INSTALLDIR" Value="C:\Live">TargetSystem = "live"</Publish>
      <Publish Event="SpawnWaitDialog" Value="WaitForCostingDlg">CostingComplete = 1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">TargetSystem = "user"</Publish>
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">
        <![CDATA[TargetSystem <> "user"]]>
      </Publish>
    </Control>

<Property Id="TargetSystem">user</Property>
```

Hope it'll help you.

Greets
- Xeno

Comment: Can you tell anything about background color. I its default gray color.

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks, Having System Path properties also can be used in place of Value.